# wpdb Cannot Access Associative Array Data in a Count Query

Tags: wpdb, array

I have two records in my custom table. I am trying to use `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM tableA` but I am not getting the results I am expecting.

The code below will echo `Array ( [0] => Array ( [total] => 2 ) )`:

```
// Count the amount of records in the table
$total = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM tableA", 'ARRAY_A' );

echo "Total Records:" . print_r( $total );
```

The code below echos nothing:

```
// Count the amount of records in the table
$total = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM tableA", 'ARRAY_A' );

echo "Total Records:" . $total[0]['total'];
```

How can I simplify this? What am I doing wrong? I'm racking my brain over this and I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify that by using `$wpdb->get_var`.

```
$total = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM tableA" );
echo "Total Records:" . $total;
```

However, the code you've got should work-- either version of it. I tested both.

The only thing I notice is that the first version of the code *should* give you `Array ( [0] => Array ( [total] => 2 ) )`. Where is `cnt` coming from?

Comment: Thanks for coming to my rescue again!

Sorry, the `cnt` is a mixup.

I've tried using the `$wpdb->get_var()` method, and it still returns as blank. I don't get it.

Comment: Sorry, I got it to work! I forgot to take out the `, ARRAY_A` when I changed the `$wpdb` methods.